# Window's Slack is frozen

Tags: windows-10, freeze, slack

The Windows app opens and loads Slack but then Slack freezes. Even the quit button doesn't work. I have to force-ably shut it down via the task manager. The Windows app's menu bar does work but some of its corresponding actions don't (like quit that just simply closes the window but does not shutdown slack). The slack website does work.
I tried

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling it on a Windows 10 x64
2. Help > Reset App Data - this resets the app but once I login to my slack account, its frozen all over again.

---

It looks like the Slack frozen yet it still receives updates for channels. I just can't navigate to any other channel, type or scroll up/down in the current channel.

Answer (score 23):

It seems its a bug that is affecting some Windows 10 users and most likely due to the Windows notifications. The temporary solution as per Slack support is

1. Ensure that you're signed into at least one team.
2. Completely quit out of Slack.
3. Hit the Windows key and R to bring up the Run dialog.
4. Type (or copy and paste) slack://notReallyWindows10 and hit Enter.

Or login to slack via the web browser.

Comment: Looked for a reference to this in Slack support and couldn't find it, but it is discussed here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/5847qa/slack_keeps_becoming_unresponsive_when_switching/

Comment: @Benj By Slack support, I meant I actually contacted Slack support. I couldn't find anything in their documentation.

Comment: Are you a member of the Windows Insider program, per chance? I know I started having this problem when I joined the program (and consequently got stuck in it).

Comment: @coderpros I have Windows 7 Pro (purchased as a student) which upgraded to Windows 10 Pro. I don't believe I'm in the Insider Program.

Comment: This didn't help in my case unfortunately. Crashed again on next notification.

Comment: Thanks. Closing slack and logging into web, then opening Slack app fixed it for me. Weird.

Answer (score 20):

Try the following: **Menu > File > Preferences > Notifications**, scroll down to **"Deliver notifications via..."** and change it to **"Slack's built-in notifications"**. Restart Slack and the problem should be gone - helped in my case.

Comment: Noticed this super annoying bug also, just kept using `@powershell kill -name slack` to kill and restart, but figured I'd try this out instead. Seems to make sense as it freezes **every time** I get a message. No longer using "Windows Action Center", we'll see how it goes with built-in notices...

Answer (score 10):

Try the following:

**Help > Troubleshooting > Clear Cache and Restart**

This has stopped it from freezing on me, at least for now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with Slack freezing up. Everything from switching channels to pasting text into the message box would lock up the Windows app. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail. I reset the app. I cleared the cache. Nothing worked.

Then... under Preferences > Advanced I checked the box to "Disable hardware acceleration".

It seems to have worked, for now anyway. No more freezing. Everything is nice and zippy again.

Answer (score 1):

Clear any Slack notifications from Windows 10 and it'll launch successfully. You know, that button in the lower right that you never use. ;) Click **Clear all notifications**.

Answer (score 0):

Slack is network dependent. If the network is down, it's broken. When Slack is down, and I can see it in the system tray, but have no interface. I have to force-quit it in Task Manager. Restarting it is no help. Reinstalling is no help.

When Slack's network is down the app is down, end of story.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Previously I put this down to low memory because it was fixed when I shut down my VM but now I believe it's down to a conflict with the clipboard when VirtualBox is running.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=101879

What seems to work for me is when it's hung, copy some text to the clipboard from Windows and it springs back into life